# Python: How do I reverse every character in a string list?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, reverse

For instance, `myList = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']`...  now I want my result to be this:

```
 ['1gnirts', '2gnirts', '3gnirts']
```

I've found few examples on how to reverse strings in general but not specific to this problem ... I'm bit confused on how to do a reverse of strings that are in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to reverse a single word, for this problem you only have to do the same for each of the words of the list:

```
def reverseWord(word):
    # one way to implement the reverse word function
    return word[::-1]

myList = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]

# apply the reverseWord function on each word using a list comprehension
reversedWords = [reverseWord(word) for word in myList]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
reversed_strings = [x[::-1] for x in myList][::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to use, the reverse function for lists, and the [::-1] to reverse strings.  This can be done as a list comprehension as follows.

```
myList.reverse
newList = [x[::-1] for x in myList]
```

Comment: if I wanted to print out without the '' [ ]' " and " , " for example like this:

 `'1gnirts 2gnirts 3gnirts'`

how do I go about doing this?

Comment: You didn't call the reverse method.

Answer (score 0):

Or

oneShot = [x[::-1] for x in myList][::-1]