# How to reverse each character of a string in a strings list and concatenate them

Tags: python, string, list, substring, reverse

For instance, `myList = (['string21', 'string43', 'string65'])`... now I want my result to be this (without [ ] and , ):

```
 '12gnirts 34gnirts 56gnirts'
```

I've found few examples on how to reverse strings in general but not specific to this problem ... I'm bit confused on how to do a reverse of strings that are in a list.

Below is my code:

```
reverseEachCharacter = [x[::-1] for x in myList]
print "Result: ", reverseEachCharacter
# prints this:['1gnirts', '2gnirts', '3gnirts']
```

Comment: You need another ' after string65. And why is your result missing a few numbers?

Comment: What is the difference to [these question and answers of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48952467/8881141) from three days ago?

Comment: You just copied and pasted the answer from older question here. Please try to search and play with your code, it is for your own good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently printing the list. `[...]` is because of it being the list. Just use `" ".join(reverseEachCharacter)` to join your strings in the list to create another string as:

```
myList = ['string21', 'string43', 'string65']
reverseEachCharacter = [x[::-1] for x in myList]
print (repr(" ".join(reverseEachCharacter)))
```

Output:

```
'12gnirts 34gnirts 56gnirts'
```

Edit: Found that `repr` is made just for printing with the quotes! Though `"'{}'".format()` will be still better for the flexibility.

Comment: I can show you how to do that, too. But why don't you try to figure it out by yourself? I see that the code you posted in question itself was from an answer to your previous question. Try to give effort from your side first :)

Comment: absolutely! but the answer you gave to the question is also wrong is what I'm saying... I can send you my tries... which I couldn't put up here because of the max length... here are my few tries: 
`addCommas = (" ' ".join(reverseEachCharacter)); 
print "My last reversed strings:",(addCommas)`

Comment: There you have my way of doing it :D

Comment: You're welcome. If you've found what you want from this answer, please mark it as accepted.